# Can i install a game on two laptops using the same cd?

Tags: pc, splinter-cell-blacklist, ghost-recon-future-soldier

I had some cash remaining on a shopping site and bought two Ubisoft games: Splinter Cell Blacklist and Ghost Recon future soldier. Can I install the games on my laptop and my brother's laptop? Or will there be a key code error?

Comment: Which Ghost Recon Game are you talking about? There's like 13 of them.

Comment: It's only a half-answer right now, but Splinter Cell Blacklist is going to have you create a UPlay account.  This will let you install it on multiple computers, but only one session is allowed on as the game will log-on each time with the new account.

Answer (score 1):

If you have both games on your Uplay account, you can install both games on both laptops, however you will only be able to be logged in on one of the 2 laptops at any time. This means you cannot play either of these games at the same time on both laptops.

Comment: What if one laptop was on offline mode and the other was online? Then the games can be played on both laptops right?

Comment: I think so yes, you must have played the game at least once to be able to play it in offline mode